# Keep getting TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, pseudocode

I am trying to translate that Pseudo-Code to Python. Here is the Pseudo-Code:

**PseudoCode:**

```
FOR Count <- 1 TO 13 DO
  OUTPUT "Please enter next digit of ISBN: "
  INPUT ISBN[Count]
ENDFOR
CalculatedDigit <- 0
Count <- 1
WHILE Count < 13 DO
  CalculatedDigit <- CalculatedDigit + ISBN[Count]
  Count <- Count + 1
  CalculatedDigit <- CalculatedDigit + ISBN[Count] * 3
  Count <- Count + 1
ENDWHILE
WHILE CalculatedDigit >= 10 DO
  CalculatedDigit <- CalculatedDigit - 10
ENDWHILE
CalculatedDigit <- 10 - CalculatedDigit
IF CalculatedDigit = 10
  THEN CalculatedDigit <- 0
ENDIF
IF CalculatedDigit = ISBN[13]
  THEN OUTPUT "Valid ISBN"
  ELSE OUTPUT "Invalid ISBN"
ENDIF
```

**Python:**

```
for Count in range(1,13):
  print("Please enter next digit of ISBN:")
  ISBN = int(input(">"))
  ISBN[Count]
CalculatedDigit = 0
Count = 1
while Count < 13:
  CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit + ISBN
  Count = Count + 1
  CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit + ISBN * 3
  Count = Count + 1
while CalculatedDigit >= 10:
  CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit - 10
  CalculatedDigit = 10 - CalculatedDigit
if CalculatedDigit == 10:
  CalculatedDigit = 0
if CalculatedDigit == ISBN[13]:
  print("Valid ISBN")
else:
  print("Invalid ISBN")
```

I really have no idea why I get this error 
**TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you think is the problem? What have you tried? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, in many cases trying to do a *minimal* (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example often helps to find the answer on your on.

Answer (score 0):

```
ISBN = int(input(">"))
```

`ISBN` is an integer.

```
ISBN[Count]
```

Trying to access position `Count` of `ISBN`.  But you can't because integers are not subscriptable

What to do instead:

```
ISBN = list(map(int, input('Please enter full ISBN: ')))
```

ISBN is now a list of integers, and should work as you expect.

Comment: there are other errors like that in that code: `if CalculatedDigit == ISBN[13]:`

Comment: @AnasYusef I edited that into my post.  Refresh your page

Comment: I am trying to translate the pseudocode that I just added. Apologies for any inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

ISBN is not an array.

An array:
`ISBN = [1,2,3,4]`

Accessing an array:
`ISBN[2]` will return `3`

What exactly are you trying to do with it?

Comment: ISBN are serial numbers for books.  They have a check digit.  He's trying to validate ISBN numbers

Answer (score 0):

Think it through.

```
a = 5
print(a[1])
```

What would you expect this to print?

Numbers aren't lists. By using `[]`s, you're trying to access something contained within the object, but ints don't contain anything! They're just numbers.